# Electron : How to print only a part of html (div) in electron silently?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, chromium

What i am trying to achieve is that the web page which is **remotely** hosted and is being loaded in my electron app would want the **Electron** app to print only a particular **div** element . I know if i use  `webContents.print({silent:true})` the entire page would get printed silently . But i want the same thing to happen on only a particular div . 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to send the div a new hidden window and then print from there.

---

### main.js

```
app.on('ready', function(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1080, height:720})
  workerWindow = new BrowserWindow();
  workerWindow.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/printerWindow.html");
  workerWindow.hide();
});

// retransmit it to workerWindow
ipcMain.on("printPDF", function(event, content){
  workerWindow.webContents.send("printPDF", content);
});

// when worker window is ready
ipcMain.on("readyToPrintPDF", (event) => {
  workerWindow.webContents.print({silent: true});
})
```

---

### controller.js

```
// target the object you want to print and send it to the new window
ipcRenderer.send("printPDF", div_to_be_targeted);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to load a URL and send a specific div from that loaded page to our window?